# Google Spreadsheet ID changed after upgrading to "new Google Sheets"

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

When Google Sheets automatically updated my sheet to "New Google Sheets" its Google ID changed.

This happened without warning, and affected a server I run which effectively makes a specific Google Sheet a CMS.

Clearly these IDs are not intended to be permanent.

How should I specify which Google Sheet I'm referring to if not by ID.

Comment: Yeah, it messed my system right up though, I had databases keyed by Google sheet ID. However I haven't heard any reports of others running in to difficulties, what is everyone else doing differently?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this function
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(name)